Использование join и detach c++
Имеется следующий код:
class MyClass {
public:
    void doWork() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tdoWork started\t" << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tdoWork stopped\t" << "\n";
    };

    void doWork2(int a) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tdoWork2 started\t" << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        std::cout << "Значение параметра doWork2 " << a;
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tdoWork2 stopped\t" << "\n";
    };

    int sum(int a, int b) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tsum started\t" << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tsum stopped\t" << "\n";
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    MyClass class1;
    std::thread th1(&MyClass::doWork, class1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << "ID потока: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\tmain work\t" << i << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    };

    th1.join();
    return 0;
}

Я ведь правильно понимаю, что join нужен для того, чтобы если main завершился раньше, программа дождалась выполнения созданного th1 потока?
Также не очень понимаю случаи, когда нужен detach.
detach же просто "отправит поток в свободное плавание", как тогда забрать из него результат и в каких кейсах применять его вместо join?
Спасибо

join, позволяет дождаться завершения работы потока, detach открепляет системный поток от объекта, теряя его идентификатор, и он становится сам по себе, никак его уже не получить, и не дождаться от него результата.

В общем случае про "забрать результат" - это уже std::future.

После запуска потока экземпляр std::thread становится владельцем запущенного потока. Блокирующий вызов join дожидается завершения потока и освобождает ассоциированные ресурсы, обеспечивая возможность корректно завершить жизнь ранее созданных объектов, на которые мог ссылаться код в завершенном потоке. Этот вызов является обязательным. Вызов деструктора экземпляра std::thread, который еще является владельцем запущенного потока приводит к аварийному завершению программы.
Вызовы detach в грамотном коде не нужны и обычно являются грубой ошибкой. Единственная ситуация, когда их использование можно как-то оправдать - вызов в потоке сторонней функции, блокирующей его на неопределенное время. Тогда вызов detach можно использовать как менее убогую альтернативу преднамерреной утечке ресурсов при создании потока посредством new без соответствующего вызова delete.
В С++20 появлися класс std::jthread, который имеет встроенный механизм оповещения о необходимости завершения потока и сам вызывает join в деструкторе.

Насчет detach не совсем согласен. Если это вычислительный поток, результат которого должен быть использован - дело одно. А если какой-то вспомогательный, ожидающий и т.п. - вполне нормальным решением может быть именно detach.

@Harry ¿Что именно подразумевается под "вспомогательный, ожидающий" и как в этом случае обходить проблемы с временем жизни объектов (причем заметьте, проблемы не только в плане того, что где-то будет обращение к мертвым объектам, а еще с детекцией утечки ресурсов при выходе) и проблемы с ранним завершением работы приложения (т.е. когда процесс завершается, когда поток еще не доработал)?

Ну, при окончании процесса поток автоматически убьется. А так... Ну, например, поток, который висит себе и должен при получении какого-то сигнала послать какое-то сообщение, например. И делать это должен все время, пока работает программа. Смысл при выходе к нему join применять?  Это надо - если в нем вечный цикл - добавлять свою систему отслеживания и выхода. Ведь не всегда у потока задача - отработать и завершиться. Может и - работать, пока приложение не закроется. Примерно так как-то :)

Linux позволяет создать на порядок больше detach потоков, чем тех, что нужно "подбирать" по join. Корректно завершающийся detach поток не оставляет висящих ресурсов. Результаты detach потока можно получить через переданный ему при создании адрес структуры, в которую тот положит перед завершением результат и признак своего окончания.
